# How to check the JSON Store data on the device

Tags: storage, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am working on IBM Worklight. I have developed an application using JSON Store.I have some questions related to JSON Store.
1.Does JSON Store possess size limit?
2.JSON Store stores data in file right? If I want to see the data that is in JSON Store, how can I see that on my device?
3.Does the memory of the device has any impact on the JSON Store storage?
4.While creating a project ...I found option like create --> new Worklight JSON Store. What is the actual use of it? I am not able to create a new JSON Store with that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Does JSON Store possess size limit?

Available space on the device. More details in the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_features.html).

> 2.JSON Store stores data in file right? If I want to see the data that is in JSON Store, how can I see that on my device?

Yes. More details in [the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_support.html). For example, on Android the database file is stored here: `/data/data/com.[app-name]/databases/wljsonstore/jsonstore.sqlite`

> 3.Does the memory of the device has any impact on the JSON Store storage?

JSONStore uses some amount of memory to work, like any software application. There's an section on performance in [the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_performance.html).

> 4.While creating a project ...I found option like create --> new Worklight JSON Store. What is the actual use of it? I am not able to create a new JSON Store with that option.

There's a blog post [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/using_the_worklight_5_0_5_jsonstore?lang=en) that uses the wizard. Keep in mind the blog post is very dated, it's meant for Worklight 5.0.5. Some methods used in the blog post have been deprecated and improved since, but still made backwards compatible. What I actually recommend is basing your JSONStore code on the new 6.0 sample code [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip). There's a section in the documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_wl_adapter_integration.html) that explains adapter integration and the wizard.

Comment: There it is, I saw this on my phone this morning, and said where oh where is cnandreu's long detailed answer. There it is, #dgonz.